# Error Starting a MongoDB Database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, macos

I get the following output when trying to start a MongoDB database server and the server is unable to start. I have run `mkdir -p data/db` in my project directory.

I run the command: `mongod --dbpath=data/ --port 27017`

I get the following output:

```
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=22640 port=27017 dbpath=data/ 64-bit host=Eriks-MacBook-Pro.local
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.0
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f4240c60f005be757399042dc12f6addbc3170c1
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-01-02T12:07:27.754-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "data/" } }
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-01-02T12:07:27.755-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Comment: It seems the port you are trying to open the server on is all ready in use. Can you confirm that the port 27017 is not already in use?

Comment: try the following command in the terminal: netstat -ano | grep 27017

Comment: The port is in use, but I'm not sure by what. I ran `netstat -anp tcp | grep LISTEN` and received the output: `tcp4 0 0 *.27017 *.* LISTEN`

Comment: Are you willing to kill the service currently running on this port or are willing to change the port on which mongoDB is serving? Can you post the output of the command I suggested?

Comment: Yes I would be willing to kill the service running on the port. As for your command, `-o` is an illegal option for me.

Comment: try: lsof -i :27017

Comment: Basically i want to know what is the process id that is blocking this port

Comment: The blocking process -- Name: `mongod` PID: `1620`

Comment: Run: kill -9 1620

Comment: Note this will turn off/kill the current instance of mongodb server

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I will post an answer for this issue. please accept it as the right answer for other people who face same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error logs mention that the port 27017 is already in use.

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
lsof -i :27017
```

Note the PID(process id) and run the following command to kill the service:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

**Note:** This will kill the current instance on MongoDB server